# 99 Escalade ambient light sensor location?

Tags: electrical, headlight, escalade

On the newer escalades/denali's the ambient light sensor is on the center dash. However I can not locate it on the 1999-2000 escalade/denali. I'm hesitant to take off the whole dash to see if its hidden. Can anyone confirm the location?

Comment: It looks like it's part of the rearview mirror assembly, you'd have to confirm. I don't see any other light sensors.

Comment: I wondered that but when I look up the part its shows the dash style. I will have to look at the mirror again.